# convert time stamp to time ago in php?

Tags: php

I know this question has been asked several times and I found so many tutorials, blog posts about converting timestamp to ago time in php..

I have tried countless codes and nothing seems to work for me...

I either get a blank page with no errors (i have error rerposting on my php page), or I get some strange numbers in my page..

so I thought someone here could shed a light on this for me..

Basically I am saving date like so:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

I simply save it in mysql database...

and I echo it like so:

```
 echo $date;
```

so now what I need to know is how I can convert the echo $date; to something like 1 minutes ago, 10 minutes ago, 1 hour ago etc etc every time the page closes and reopens?

I did try so many functions that I found on google and noon seem to do anything!

could someone please advise on this issue?

Thanks

EDIT:

I used this code as stated in the answer but I still get the $date echo-ed exactly the same way as its stored in the database which is this format: 2014-10-06 22:54:54

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$time1 = new DateTime($date);
$now = new DateTime();
$interval = $time1->diff($now);


if ($interval->y) $date = $interval->y . ' years';
elseif ($interval->m) $date = $interval->m . ' months';
elseif ($interval->d) $date = $interval->d . ' days';
elseif ($interval->h) $date = $interval->h . ' hours';
elseif ($interval->i) $date = $interval->i . ' minutes';


echo $date;
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php and http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php + function `diff` of it

Comment: @Cheery, not sure what I'm looking at in either pages mate! a bit of in depth explanation would be suited here I think...

Comment: look carefully.. for example here `    $d1 = new \DateTime("2013-07-31 10:29:00"); $d2 = new \DateTime("2013-08-02 5:32:12"); echo $d1->diff($d2)->d;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `DateTime` class to get the difference between 2 times, ie;

```
$time1 = new DateTime('2014-10-06 09:00:59');
$now = new DateTime();
$interval = $time1->diff($now,true);
```

and then use that difference (which is a `DateInterval` object, `$interval`) to find the smallest time difference like this;

```
if ($interval->y) echo $interval->y . ' years';
elseif ($interval->m) echo $interval->m . ' months';
elseif ($interval->d) echo $interval->d . ' days';
elseif ($interval->h) echo $interval->h . ' hours';
elseif ($interval->i) echo $interval->i . ' minutes';
else echo "less than 1 minute";
```

which should echo (at time of writing) `13 hours`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: with your first code i get Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::diff() error on my page.

Comment: Crumbs, what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: I suspect 5.2, `diff` was added in 5.3

Comment: @shell or upgrade to 5.3

Comment: switched the PHP version and it worked like a charm :D

Comment: But again that is not what i am after :(. what i was hoping to achieve  is that store the the $date as its shown my question and echo it the same way but use some sort of PHP or Javascript or convert the $date to time ago on my html/php page!

Comment: If you add `ago` to the strings above, you'll get `13 hours ago`. Is this not what you want? What's the additional issue?

Comment: see, my issue is not adding a astring to another string/numbers.. my issue is converting the $date in my code which i mentioned in my question to 1 minute, 10 minute, 1 hour, etc etc.... does that make sense?

Comment: Assign `$date` to `$time1`, or just change all the references to `$time1` to `$date` ... or instead of echoing the results, save it to `$date` ... ??

Comment: Or use `$time1 = new DateTime($date);`

Comment: done all that and nothing seems to work! please view my edit.

Comment: I've changed the `diff` to `$interval = $time1->diff($now,true);`. The `true` argument forces the difference to be positive.

Comment: Don't use `$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');`. That will set date to the current time, and obviously comparing the two will get a value of 0. Just set `$date` to the value from the database.

Comment: Also, added a failsafe of `else echo "less than 1 minute";` where if the value is less than a minute then that is echoed (which you can change to `$date =` if you wish).

Comment: sorry a bit confused now! I need to use $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); as I am saving the $date in mysql database as well!

Comment: In which case you need to specify the date you want to convert to that string in the second argument, such as `$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$date);`

Answer (score 2):

Check this function intval() - http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php
The following code should help you out

```
$seconds_ago = (time() - strtotime('2014-01-06 15:25:08'));

if ($seconds_ago >= 31536000) {
    echo "Seen " . intval($seconds_ago / 31536000) . " years ago";
} elseif ($seconds_ago >= 2419200) {
    echo "Seen " . intval($seconds_ago / 2419200) . " months ago";
} elseif ($seconds_ago >= 86400) {
    echo "Seen " . intval($seconds_ago / 86400) . " days ago";
} elseif ($seconds_ago >= 3600) {
    echo "Seen " . intval($seconds_ago / 3600) . " hours ago";
} elseif ($seconds_ago >= 60) {
    echo "Seen " . intval($seconds_ago / 60) . " minutes ago";
} else {
    echo "Seen less than a minute ago";
}
```